# How can I know the duplicate input element value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to web dev and jQuery. I have input element binded with blur event.

This is my code:

```
// this are my input elements:
<input class="input_name" value="bert" />
<input class="input_name" value="king kong" />
<input class="input_name" value="john" />
<input class="input_name" value="john" />

<script>

    $(".input_name").bind("blur",function(){
          alert(findDuplicate($(this).val()));
    })

    function findDuplicate(value){
          var result = 0;
          $(".input_name").each(function{
                 if($(this).val == value){
                        result++;
                 }
          });
    }

</script>
```

my main problem is when i change bert to john it returns me 3 result. how would i exempt the event sender from being checked?

Comment: Couldn't you just subtract 1?

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors in your code like $(this).val should be $(this).val() and function on each should have () at the end of function

Comment: @Anton The anonymous function passed to `each` does not need parentheses at the end.

Comment: simple solution :) var result = -1;

Comment: @Asad I agree, I would just set result to -1 initially, though.  You'll get a match on itself, taking it up to 0, then you see any actual duplicates in positive results.

Comment: Yes, there are any number of ways you could do the arithmetic

Comment: @Asad Console logs a syntax error if () doesn't exist http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/5sYQ3/ or what do you mean?

Comment: @Anton Ah I see what you mean. I didn't spot the missing parentheses after the `function` keyword, and thought you were talking about putting parentheses after the entire `function(){...}`

Answer (score 2):

Like others have mentioned, you've got a few syntax errors.  Also, rather than explicitly iterating over all the inputs, you could just have jQuery find them for you using selectors:

```
$(".input_name").bind("blur",function(){
    alert(findDuplicate($(this).val()));
})

function findDuplicate(value){
    return $(".input_name[value='" + value + "']").length - 1;
}
```

Comment: That won't really work, since value attribute stays the same http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/5sYQ3/1/

Comment: @Anton What do you mean?  That fiddle works for me as expected. OP didn't state that the values would change, so this should suffice.

Comment: That's true if the values don't change then it's all fine

Comment: @Anton Right, and given what we know about the problem, I think that's a valid solution.

Comment: then how could i change the background of other 2 input? btw thanks for the answer i think i need to explor jquery selector

Comment: @JoeyEstrada You can use the same selector, and just take a look at jQuery's .css() call: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".input_name").bind("blur", function () {
    alert(findDuplicate(this.value));
})

function findDuplicate(value) {
    var result = 0;
    $(".input_name").each(function(){
        if (this.value == value) {
            result++;
        }
    });
    return result - 1;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/Wm4HS/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
$(".input_name").bind("blur",function(){
    var nth = $(this).index();
    alert(findDuplicate($(this).val(),nth));
})

function findDuplicate(value,nth){
      var result = 0;
      $(".input_name").each(function{
             if($(this).val == value && nth != index){
                    result++;
             }
      });
      return result;
}
```